# The Orthogonal Projection of a 4-cube to 3-Space

Tags: geometry

Good day

I am not a mathematician by trade but have some university education  in both Mathematics and Applied Mathematics (be that some 30 years ago).

I am currently fascinated by the problem of an orthogonal projection of a vector in 4-D space to a 3-D space.

As a starting point, if we hold a wire frame of a 3-Cube to a flat screen (a 2-D space) such that the cube face closest to the screen is parallel to the screen.

i.e.

imagine a cube floating above a plane, with light coming from an infinite distance above the plane: the cube casts a polygonal shadow.

Now the 3-cube has 6 faces. I believe that in the 2-D image we see the 6 faces  projected as follows;

2 faces projected so as to cast the Outer and Inner squares in  the 2-D image and 4 faces project to show the 4 rhombi enclosing the inner projected square. I hope this is correct.

Now essentially I see this as the Orthogonal Projection of a cube in 3-D to a space in 2-D ( a subspace of 3-D).

The Orthogonal Decomposition  Theorem states that

Let W be a subspace of Rn. Then each vector Y in Rn can be uniquely represented in the form;

Y = Y(hat) + z

Where; Y(hat) is an element of the subspace W (Orthogonal Projection Space)

And

z is an element of the W "perp" being the orthogonal compliment space.

Now I may be wrong but I am trying to interpret the projection of the 3-Cube to 2-Space in this way. I am thinking (subject to correction) that there are 2 sets of projected faces of the 3-Cube to 2-D because one set is the Orthogonal Projection (in W) and the other is the Orthogonal Compliment Projection (in  W “perp”).  I may be completely wrong here.

If I am correct then my question is;

Which of the two sets of Projected  faces is the Orthogonal Projection and which is the Orthogonal Compliment Projection ?

My guess is that the 2 faces which cast the inner and outer squares are Orthogonaly Projected while the 4 other faces are Orthogonal Compliment Projected.

Your thoughts on the above would be appreciated.

Once I have an understanding of this then I want to switch the problem to a 4-Cube projected in this manner to a 3-D space and ask to same questions.

Thanking you.

Paul Hinrichsen.

Comment: Good question. Google search for _tesseract projections_ will give you lots of pages (including wikipedia) and lots of images.

Comment: If light is coming from infinitely far away and one face is parallel to the plane, I would think the projected image would be a square....unless of course the light comes in at an angle

Comment: The projection of the 3-cube that you describe is not orthogonal. In an orthogonal projection, edges perpendicular to the image plane collapse to a single point, so the image of the cube under this projection is a square (really two squares superimposed). This would be no different with a 4-cube projected orthogonally onto a plane parallel to to one of its faces: the image will be a square. To see any of the edges that are perpendicular to the image plane, you must use an oblique projection of some sort.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your responses. Yes after posting I realized that the light had to  come from infinity and parallel for the projections to be orthogonal. Yes the vectors perpendicular to the plane of projection would collapse to points (thank you) while the 2 faces parallel to the projection screen would image as one square on top of the other (thank you). Since the Orthogonal Decomposition Theorem states that the projection (if I have it  right) is the sum of the Orthogonal Projection (the squares) and the Orthogonal Compliment Projection (the points).

Comment: Now mathematically we describe the orthogonal Projection as the vector being projected (being a member of the space Rn) dotted into the set of basis vectors of the projection space (being a subspace of Rn). So how do we mathematically define the Orthogonal Compliment Projection? Ignoring here the trivial answer that it equals the original vector - the orthogonaly projected part  ? Perhaps as the original vector dotted into   the basis of the compliment space? Except that if we are projecting a 4 cube into 3 space the orthog projection space has 3 dim while the compliment space would be 1 dimen